# Spring Integration WS Response Soap Headers

Tags: spring-integration

I have the below use case.

1. Request is received by the ws-inbound gateway of service1.
2. Service1 Passes the request to another ws-outbound gateway service2
3. Service2 ws inbound gateway has an interceptor configured, which adds a custom soap header to the response
4. the response from service 2 is passed to the output channel of service 1 (Final response).

I am able to see that soap header is added by printing the soap envelope in interceptor (service2), but it is not present in the final response. Any pointers to solve this issue will be helpful

Comment: Let us no if you really need SOAP model for the first service. Maybe just raw HTTP proxying would be enough for you? I mean `<int-http:inbound-gateway> -> <int-http:outbound-gateway>`. The second one will still be the WS Adapters pair. In addition, please, confirm that you see your header over the network.

Comment: Hi,  Yes I need SOAP model for the first service also. Both the services are currently deployed in my local machine.

Comment: OK. So, give me, please, a confirmation that your header travels over the network. It doesn't matter that your services are locally, your `<int-ws:outbound-gateway>` sends a request to some `http://localhost:9999`, so the network is involved and you can intercept that traffic with some tool.

Comment: Hi, I tried to intercept Service1 and added the response headers. This time It is working fine. But If it is added in Service2 and the response is passed to service1, it is not working

Answer (score 1):

The `<int-ws:outbound-gateway>` uses `DefaultSoapHeaderMapper` by default.
And its logic to populate `source.getSoapAction();` and `source.getSoapHeader();`. But for that purpose you should configure `mapped-reply-headers` for your desired headers on the `<int-ws:outbound-gateway>`.

Comment: Hi, tried mapped-reply-headers, but did not give the expected result. Tried to intercept int-ws:outbound-gateway using ClientInterceptor. in the methods afterCompletion() and handleResponse(), I am able to see the custom response header that has been added. But when it is passed to the response channel of inbound gateway, somewhere it is getting lost.

Comment: OK. So, you should debug through the `DefaultSoapHeaderMapper` and figure out why it skips your header.

Comment: I debugged the same and found that it is copying the header. The type of the header is SaajSoapElement. Does it have something to do with copy logic? Because comments in the file "DefaultSoapHeaderMapper" says it copies only plain text headers.

Comment: So, do you say that it is skipped from the `extractUserDefinedHeaders()` because of `SaajSoapElement` not a `SoapHeaderElement` ?

Comment: It is not skipped anywhere. Both extractUserDefinedHeaders() and copyHeaders() ran successfully. And the map returned by toHeaders() method contains the header also

Comment: OK. Can you figure out where your header is removed?