# Spring Integration File Outbound Adapter

Tags: spring-integration

Is there any way we can use file outbound adapter to write the entire SOAP envelop to file rather than just payload ? (I am able to write the payload into a file).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you use there `<int-ws:inbound-gateway>`. Or it doesn't matter for the target solution...

You should implement some `EndpointInterceptor` add it to the `UriEndpointMapping`. With the `handleRequest` implementation you have access to the whole `MessageContext` where you are able to do something like:

```
((SoapMessage) messageContext.getRequest()).getEnvelope()
```

And send this object to the channel for the `outbound-channel-adapter` to `stream` its `Source` to the file.

From the gateway perspective you don't have the access to the `messageContext` anymore.

**UPDATE**

According to your comment below (please, consider to place similar info in the question directly in the future), I can suggests something like `headers` trick:

You implement custom `SoapHeaderMapper` (`extends DefaultSoapHeaderMapper`) and overriding `toHeadersFromRequest()` store passed in `SoapMessage` to your won header and use it the same way as we discussed in the `EndpointInterceptor` case. From the `<int-file:outbound-channel-adapter>` perspective you just should consult that header to extract the `Source` and its `InputStream` to store in the file.

**UPDATE 2**

```
public class MySoapHeaderMapper extends DefaultSoapHeaderMapper {

    @Override
    public Map<String, Object> toHeadersFromRequest(SoapMessage source) {
        Map<String, Object> headers = super.toHeadersFromRequest(source);
        headers.put("soapMessage", source);
        return headers;
    }

}
```

You should inject it into `<int-ws:inbound-gateway>` as a `header-mapper`. Afterwards that `soapMessage` header will be available in any downstream component. E.g.

```
<chain input-channel="storeToFile">
    <transformer expression="headers.soapMessage.envelope.source.inputStream"/>
    <int-file:outbound-channel-adapter /> 
</chain>
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your reply. But my use case is little different. After receiving the request in <int-ws:inbound-gateway>, i have to pass the same to few service activators for some validation and header enrichment. After that I am sending the message to a pub sub channel (say channelPubSub). One of the consumer of this channel is file adapter, which writes the message to file. In this scenario, can we use end point interceeptors?

Comment: See an UPDATE in my answer.

Comment: Sorry.. I did not understand it completely. Could you please show me some sample, if possible?

Comment: Hi. I got it. But how will I achieve the functionality which is provided by mapped-request-headers="*", inside  toHeadersFromRequest() ? Because the incoming SOAP message is having many header section.

Comment: :-) Let's discuss that in your appropriate question! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34778794/spring-integration-ws-response-soap-headers